# .net Runtime - Silverlight Runtime =?

Tags: .net, silverlight, frameworks, clr, silverlight-2.0

I've googled around a bit, and I haven't been able to find a good listing of what classes from the .net CLR are not included in the 'CoreCLR' aka Silverlight.

**What is Silverlight missing from the Windows .net Framework?**

Also, is there anything that the Silverlight runtime has that the .net Framework doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight Runtime (Silverlight CLR) is essentially a mini-mini CLR :).

Microsoft did the work of removing many dependencies to .NET Framework assemblies not part of the Silverlight release

> Silverlight CLR is a subset of the
>   .NET Framework that contains
>   components and libraries, including
>   data integration, extensible Windows
>   controls, networking, base class
>   libraries, garbage collection, and the
>   common language runtime (CLR).
>
> Some parts of the .NET Framework for
>   Silverlight are deployed with your
>   application. These "Silverlight
>   Libraries" are assemblies not included
>   in the Silverlight runtime and are
>   instead shipped in the Silverlight
>   SDK. When Silverlight Libraries are
>   used in your application, they are
>   packaged up with your application and
>   downloaded to the browser. These
>   include new UI controls, XLINQ,
>   Syndication (RSS/Atom), XML
>   serialization, and the dynamic
>   language runtime (DLR).

To read about a detailed comparison, see this link http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/10/01/comparing-silverlight-and-the-net-framework.aspx

Comment: Right, I'm probably butchering the terminology, sorry.
What I'm trying to say is: what classes ARE available in standard .net that AREN'T included in Silverlight.
I guess I'm talking about the BCL, right? Let me know if I can phrase this better.  Thanx!

Comment: 3 lines of code into my first Silverlight app and I've noticed that TypeDesciptor is missing. Not cool.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the online [Silverlight 2 Documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838158(vs.95).aspx) which includes API documentation.

Or go to the [Silverlight 2 Getting Started Page](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/) and either download the addins for Visual Studio 2008 if you have it (it works with the free Visual Web Developer Express if you don't have Visual Studio 2008) or download the Silverlight 2 SDK which is listed lower on the Getting Started page.

Once you have the Silverlight 2 SDK installed, you can launch Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Silverlight 2 -> Welcome, which has links to the installed documentation as well as other resources.